# Laravel: Meaning of the" ::class" in config file

Tags: php, laravel

I just am curious and want to know, what is it about with this obviously interesting expression `::class`. Is there a `CONST` called `class` in the static classes scope? I didn't find anything using Google, so I thought to ask here.

Hopefully someone is able to explain it to me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way to return namespaced fully qualified class name. Check out PHP5 [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that (introduced in 5.5).